# Column 'image' cannot be null

Tags: php, mysql, image, post, blogs

I have my database set up, and my php form uploads the image to the folder I want it to just fine. However, in the database it just says null for the image, if I change that to not be null, I get an error saying:
**Notice: Undefined index: image in C:\xampp\htdocs\sws_blog\admin\add_image_post.php on line 45
Column 'image' cannot be null**

I am trying to build a custom PHP blog that ONLY I will be posting/uploading to. I have different post types such as "Image Posts" and "Video Posts".

I cannot get the image to show for that post I uploaded the image with..

Here is my add_image_post.php:

```
    <?php require_once('../Connections/blog.php'); ?>
<?php
if (!function_exists("GetSQLValueString")) {
function GetSQLValueString($theValue, $theType, $theDefinedValue = "", $theNotDefinedValue = "") 
{
  if (PHP_VERSION < 6) {
    $theValue = get_magic_quotes_gpc() ? stripslashes($theValue) : $theValue;
  }

  $theValue = function_exists("mysql_real_escape_string") ? mysql_real_escape_string($theValue) : mysql_escape_string($theValue);

  switch ($theType) {
    case "text":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? "'" . $theValue . "'" : "NULL";
      break;    
    case "long":
    case "int":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? intval($theValue) : "NULL";
      break;
    case "double":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? doubleval($theValue) : "NULL";
      break;
    case "date":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? "'" . $theValue . "'" : "NULL";
      break;
    case "defined":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? $theDefinedValue : $theNotDefinedValue;
      break;
  }
  return $theValue;
}
}

$editFormAction = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
if (isset($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'])) {
  $editFormAction .= "?" . htmlentities($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']);
}

if ((isset($_POST["MM_insert"])) && ($_POST["MM_insert"] == "imageform")) {
  $insertSQL = sprintf("INSERT INTO iposts (title, tags, teaser, ipost, image) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s)",
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['title'], "text"),
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['tags'], "text"),
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['teaser'], "text"),
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['ipost'], "text"),
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['image'], "text"));

  mysql_select_db($database_blog, $blog);
  $Result1 = mysql_query($insertSQL, $blog) or die(mysql_error());

  $insertGoTo = "manage_posts.php";
  if (isset($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'])) {
    $insertGoTo .= (strpos($insertGoTo, '?')) ? "&" : "?";
    $insertGoTo .= $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];
  }
  header(sprintf("Location: %s", $insertGoTo));
}

if ((isset($_POST["MM_insert"])) && ($_POST["MM_insert"] == "imageform")) {
  $insertSQL = sprintf("INSERT INTO iposts (title, tags, teaser, ipost, image) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s)",
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['title'], "text"),
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['tags'], "text"),
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['teaser'], "text"),
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['ipost'], "text"),
                       GetSQLValueString($_FILES["image"], "name"));
  $allowedExts = array("gif", "jpeg", "jpg", "png");
$temp = explode(".", $_FILES["image"]["name"]);
$extension = end($temp);
if ((($_FILES["image"]["type"] == "image/gif")
|| ($_FILES["image"]["type"] == "image/jpeg")
|| ($_FILES["image"]["type"] == "image/jpg")
|| ($_FILES["image"]["type"] == "image/pjpeg")
|| ($_FILES["image"]["type"] == "image/x-png")
|| ($_FILES["image"]["type"] == "image/png"))
&& ($_FILES["image"]["size"] < 200000) // <= you may have to increase this value
&& in_array($extension, $allowedExts))
  {
  if ($_FILES["image"]["error"] > 0)
    {
    echo "Return Code: " . $_FILES["image"]["error"] . "<br>";
    }
  else
    {
    echo "Upload: " . $_FILES["image"]["name"] . "<br>";
    echo "Type: " . $_FILES["image"]["type"] . "<br>";
    echo "Size: " . ($_FILES["image"]["size"] / 1024) . " kB<br>";
    echo "Temp file: " . $_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"] . "<br>";

    if (file_exists("uploads/" . $_FILES["image"]["name"]))
      {
      echo $_FILES["image"]["name"] . " already exists. ";
      }
    else
      {
      move_uploaded_file($_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"],
      "uploads/" . $_FILES["image"]["name"]);
      echo "Stored in: " . "uploads/" . $_FILES["image"]["name"];
      }
    }
  }
else
  {
     echo "Invalid file";
  }                   
  mysql_select_db($database_blog, $blog);
  $Result1 = mysql_query($insertSQL, $blog) or die(mysql_error());

  $insertGoTo = "manage_posts.php";
  if (isset($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'])) {
    $insertGoTo .= (strpos($insertGoTo, '?')) ? "&" : "?";
    $insertGoTo .= $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];
  }
  header(sprintf("Location: %s", $insertGoTo));
}
?>
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Add Image Post</title>
<link href="../css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="../css/bootstrap-responsive.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="../css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>
<body>
<h1>Add Image Post </h1>
<p><a href="index.php">Admin Menu</a></p>
<form action="<?php echo $editFormAction; ?>" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="imageform" id="imageform">
  <p>
    <label for="title">Title:</label>
    <input name="title" type="text" id="title" maxlength="30">
  </p>
  <p>
    <label for="tags">Tags:</label>
    <input name="tags" type="text" id="tags" maxlength="30">
  </p>
  <p>
    <label for="teaser">Teaser:</label>
    <textarea name="teaser" id="teaser"></textarea>
  </p>
  <p>
    <label for="ipost">Post:</label>
    <textarea name="ipost" id="ipost"></textarea>
  </p>
  <p>
    <label for="image">Filename:</label>
    <input type="file" name="image" id="image">
  </p>
  <p>
    <input name="insert" type="submit" class="submit" id="insert" value="Post">
  </p>
  <input type="hidden" name="MM_insert" value="imageform">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

**Manage_Posts.php**

```
<?php require_once('../Connections/blog.php'); ?>
<?php
if (!function_exists("GetSQLValueString")) {
function GetSQLValueString($theValue, $theType, $theDefinedValue = "", $theNotDefinedValue = "") 
{
  if (PHP_VERSION < 6) {
    $theValue = get_magic_quotes_gpc() ? stripslashes($theValue) : $theValue;
  }

  $theValue = function_exists("mysql_real_escape_string") ? mysql_real_escape_string($theValue) : mysql_escape_string($theValue);

  switch ($theType) {
    case "text":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? "'" . $theValue . "'" : "NULL";
      break;    
    case "long":
    case "int":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? intval($theValue) : "NULL";
      break;
    case "double":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? doubleval($theValue) : "NULL";
      break;
    case "date":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? "'" . $theValue . "'" : "NULL";
      break;
    case "defined":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? $theDefinedValue : $theNotDefinedValue;
      break;
  }
  return $theValue;
}
}

$currentPage = $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"];

$maxRows_getIposts = 10;
$pageNum_getIposts = 0;
if (isset($_GET['pageNum_getIposts'])) {
  $pageNum_getIposts = $_GET['pageNum_getIposts'];
}
$startRow_getIposts = $pageNum_getIposts * $maxRows_getIposts;

mysql_select_db($database_blog, $blog);
$query_getIposts = "SELECT post_id, title, updated FROM iposts ORDER BY updated DESC";
$query_limit_getIposts = sprintf("%s LIMIT %d, %d", $query_getIposts, $startRow_getIposts, $maxRows_getIposts);
$getIposts = mysql_query($query_limit_getIposts, $blog) or die(mysql_error());
$row_getIposts = mysql_fetch_assoc($getIposts);

if (isset($_GET['totalRows_getIposts'])) {
  $totalRows_getIposts = $_GET['totalRows_getIposts'];
} else {
  $all_getIposts = mysql_query($query_getIposts);
  $totalRows_getIposts = mysql_num_rows($all_getIposts);
}
$totalPages_getIposts = ceil($totalRows_getIposts/$maxRows_getIposts)-1;$maxRows_getIposts = 10;
$pageNum_getIposts = 0;
if (isset($_GET['pageNum_getIposts'])) {
  $pageNum_getIposts = $_GET['pageNum_getIposts'];
}
$startRow_getIposts = $pageNum_getIposts * $maxRows_getIposts;

mysql_select_db($database_blog, $blog);
$query_getIposts = "SELECT post_id, title, image, updated FROM iposts ORDER BY updated DESC";
$query_limit_getIposts = sprintf("%s LIMIT %d, %d", $query_getIposts, $startRow_getIposts, $maxRows_getIposts);
$getIposts = mysql_query($query_limit_getIposts, $blog) or die(mysql_error());
$row_getIposts = mysql_fetch_assoc($getIposts);

if (isset($_GET['totalRows_getIposts'])) {
  $totalRows_getIposts = $_GET['totalRows_getIposts'];
} else {
  $all_getIposts = mysql_query($query_getIposts);
  $totalRows_getIposts = mysql_num_rows($all_getIposts);
}
$totalPages_getIposts = ceil($totalRows_getIposts/$maxRows_getIposts)-1;

$maxRows_getVposts = 10;
$pageNum_getVposts = 0;
if (isset($_GET['pageNum_getVposts'])) {
  $pageNum_getVposts = $_GET['pageNum_getVposts'];
}
$startRow_getVposts = $pageNum_getVposts * $maxRows_getVposts;

mysql_select_db($database_blog, $blog);
$query_getVposts = "SELECT post_id, title, updated FROM vposts ORDER BY updated DESC";
$query_limit_getVposts = sprintf("%s LIMIT %d, %d", $query_getVposts, $startRow_getVposts, $maxRows_getVposts);
$getVposts = mysql_query($query_limit_getVposts, $blog) or die(mysql_error());
$row_getVposts = mysql_fetch_assoc($getVposts);

if (isset($_GET['totalRows_getVposts'])) {
  $totalRows_getVposts = $_GET['totalRows_getVposts'];
} else {
  $all_getVposts = mysql_query($query_getVposts);
  $totalRows_getVposts = mysql_num_rows($all_getVposts);
}
$totalPages_getVposts = ceil($totalRows_getVposts/$maxRows_getVposts)-1;

$queryString_getIposts = "";
if (!empty($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'])) {
  $params = explode("&", $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']);
  $newParams = array();
  foreach ($params as $param) {
    if (stristr($param, "pageNum_getIposts") == false && 
        stristr($param, "totalRows_getIposts") == false) {
      array_push($newParams, $param);
    }
  }
  if (count($newParams) != 0) {
    $queryString_getIposts = "&" . htmlentities(implode("&", $newParams));
  }
}
$queryString_getIposts = sprintf("&totalRows_getIposts=%d%s", $totalRows_getIposts, $queryString_getIposts);

$queryString_getVposts = "";
if (!empty($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'])) {
  $params = explode("&", $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']);
  $newParams = array();
  foreach ($params as $param) {
    if (stristr($param, "pageNum_getVposts") == false && 
        stristr($param, "totalRows_getVposts") == false) {
      array_push($newParams, $param);
    }
  }
  if (count($newParams) != 0) {
    $queryString_getVposts = "&" . htmlentities(implode("&", $newParams));
  }
}
$queryString_getVposts = sprintf("&totalRows_getVposts=%d%s", $totalRows_getVposts, $queryString_getVposts);
?>
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Manage Posts</title>
<link href="../css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="../css/bootstrap-responsive.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="../css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>
    <body>
<h1>Manage Posts
</h1>
<p><a href="index.php">Admin menu</a></p>
<p><a href="add_image_post.php">Add Image Post</a></p>
<p><a href="add_video_post.php">Add Video Post</a></p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<h3>Image Posts</h3>
<table width="800">
  <tr>
    <th scope="col">Image</th>
    <th scope="col">Date</th>
    <th scope="col">Title</th>
    <th scope="col">&nbsp;</th>
    <th scope="col">&nbsp;</th>
  </tr>
  <?php do { ?>
    <tr>
      <td><img src="uploads/<?php echo $_FILES["image"] ["name"]?>" width="100" border="0"></a></td>
      <td><?php echo $row_getIposts['updated']; ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $row_getIposts['title']; ?></td>
      <td><a href="update_image_post.php?post_id=<?php echo $row_getIposts['post_id']; ?>">EDIT</a></td>
      <td><a href="delete_post.php?post_id=<?php echo $row_getIposts['post_id']; ?>">DELETE</a></td>
    </tr>
    <?php } while ($row_getIposts = mysql_fetch_assoc($getIposts)); ?>
</table>
<table border="0">
  <tr>
    <td><?php if ($pageNum_getIposts > 0) { // Show if not first page ?>
        <a href="<?php printf("%s?pageNum_getIposts=%d%s", $currentPage, 0, $queryString_getIposts); ?>">First</a>
    <?php } // Show if not first page ?></td>
    <td><?php if ($pageNum_getIposts > 0) { // Show if not first page ?>
        <a href="<?php printf("%s?pageNum_getIposts=%d%s", $currentPage, max(0, $pageNum_getIposts - 1), $queryString_getIposts); ?>">Previous</a>
    <?php } // Show if not first page ?></td>
    <td><?php if ($pageNum_getIposts < $totalPages_getIposts) { // Show if not last page ?>
        <a href="<?php printf("%s?pageNum_getIposts=%d%s", $currentPage, min($totalPages_getIposts, $pageNum_getIposts + 1), $queryString_getIposts); ?>">Next</a>
    <?php } // Show if not last page ?></td>
    <td><?php if ($pageNum_getIposts < $totalPages_getIposts) { // Show if not last page ?>
        <a href="<?php printf("%s?pageNum_getIposts=%d%s", $currentPage, $totalPages_getIposts, $queryString_getIposts); ?>">Last</a>
    <?php } // Show if not last page ?></td>
  </tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
<?php
mysql_free_result($getIposts);
```

Comment: in one `insert`, you're using `$_POST['image']` and in the other you're using `$_FILES['image']`.  is this intentional?  also, which line is 45?  the error is happening because you value you're trying to insert for image is null... so now we have to figure out why it is null.  is it getting passed wrong?  are you referencing the wrong thing? the right thing incorrectly?

Comment: also, that function, `GetSQLValueString`... when you use it for the image, you pass `name` as a second parameter in the second insert.  it does not have a case to handle that.  what is being returned?  do both `$_FILES['image']` and `$_POST['image']` exist and have the value you expect?

Comment: The $POST['image'] was initially used to save the path to the image in the database. But I am not fully understanding how that is achieved. How would I rename the uploaded image to correlate with that post?

Answer (score 0):

```
GetSQLValueString($_POST['image'], "text"));
```

Should be

```
GetSQLValueString($_FILES['image']['name'], "text"));
```

---

And probably

```
GetSQLValueString($_FILES["image"], "name"));
```

Should be also

```
GetSQLValueString($_FILES['image']['name'], "text"));
```

You don't have `name` as `$theType` in your `switch` cases.